# Is Selected Buildings in Mapbox get highlighted incorrectly

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

The intended logic is, that the building should get highlighted depending the provided coordinates. To achieve that, we get building feature from the selected position and change the color.

The Problem is that some of the buildings still do not get highlighted fully, because sometimes provided features still are not enough to select a building fully or there are more features than expected (this can be solved with just highlighting everything returned from the targeted position). Also attaching an image.

I tried to find a proper example of this functionality in Mapbox examples but could not. Can you please suggest anything to always get all the features of targeted building. Thank you.

[image: Example of the building highlight issue]